# Search rows for matches with specified key words

Tags: r

For the specified df, I was wondering how do I go about searching all fields in each row with the specified keywords and if there is a match on the same row regardless of which column then a new column will indicate "yes" and NA for mismatches. Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("hi", "are", "you", "okay"),
                 b = c("I", "am", "okay", "thanks"),
                 c = c("how", "are", "you", "okay"))


keywords <- c("are", "you")
```

Desired results

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("hi", "are", "you", "okay"),
                 b = c("I", "am", "okay", "thanks"),
                 c = c("how", "are", "you", "okay"),
                 match = c(NA, "yes", "yes", NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using the `apply` function and the logical grep.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("hi", "are", "you", "okay"),
                 b = c("I", "am", "okay", "thanks"),
                 c = c("how", "are", "you", "okay"))
keywords <- c("are", "you")

#collapse keyword list into regular expression separated by the OR operator
searchstring<-paste0(keywords, collapse = "|")

#search by row and return TRUE FALSE
df$match<-apply(df, 1, function(row) {any(grepl(searchstring, row))})
df
```